# Less messy and faster way to solve euler-like method problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

if $f(x+1) = f(x-1) + 2f(x)$ for $x = 2,3,4,....$ and $f(1) =1$ and $f(2) = 1$, then $f(5) =?$

I could set it up in a list fashion, but is there a easier method to solve?

Answer (score 2):

Since this particular question is only asking for $f(5)$, it would be easiest to build the sequence to the fifth term.
If you want to be hardcore and find a closed form for $f(n)$, check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Theorem) out.

Answer (score 1):

The equation gives: $x^2 - 2x - 1 = 0 \to x = 1 \pm \sqrt{2}$. Thus the general solution is:

$x_n = A(1-\sqrt{2})^n + B(1+\sqrt{n})^n$, and $x_1 = x_2 = 1$ allows you to solve for $A$, and $B$.